# how to generate Frontend URI in Scheduler Command (TYPO3 9)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

What is the best way to generate frontend URIs in a scheduler command in TYPO3 v9.

I have seen attempts by initializing the TSFE manually, but for me this seems fishy.
Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 23):

The proper way to create links in any context (FE/BE/CLI) is by using the `PageRouter`. This router is always attached to a [site](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html), so you will need to retrieve the correct site first, e.g. by using the `SiteFinder`. After that you can use `PageRouter::generateUri()`.

Complete example:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteFinder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

$site = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SiteFinder::class)->getSiteByPageId($pageUid);
$arguments = [
    'foo' => 1,
];

// E.g.: "https://example.org/slug-of-page/?foo=1&cHash=..."
$uri = (string)$site->getRouter()->generateUri((string)$pageUid, $arguments);
```

Notice that this API knows nothing about Extbase and passes through `$arguments` to the URI so if you need to mimic the behavior of the Extbase `UriBuilder` you'll need to do that yourself:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\ExtensionService;

$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$extensionService = $objectManager->get(ExtensionService::class);
// E.g. "tx_acme_test"
$argumentsPrefix = $extensionService->getPluginNamespace($extensionName, $pluginName);
$arguments = [
    $argumentsPrefix => [
      'action' => $actionName, // E.g. "bar"
      'controller' => $controllerName, // E.g. "Foo"
      'foo' => 42,
    ],
];

// E.g.: "https://example.org/slug-of-page/?tx_acme_test[action]=bar&tx_acme_test[controller]=Foo&tx_acme_test[foo]=42&cHash=..."
// Or with a route enhancer: "https://example.org/slug-of-page/detail/slug-of-foo"
$uri = (string)$site->getRouter()->generateUri((string)$pageUid, $arguments);
```

Comment: If you generate a link in development system, you need to set the `TYPO3_CONTEXT` in order to get the right domain. This can be done by calling the CLI like this: `TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development php typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 myext:myclass`. Another way is setting the context your home directory (Linux or Mac) in `.profile` or `.bashrc`. Add a line `export TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development` there.

Comment: `$arguments` must contain the key `_language` with its value corresponding to `$pageUid`'s language. Otherwise, for translated pages (i.e., `$pageUid` being a page in a non-default language), the returned `$uri` will be wrong: it will be missing the required language prefix . E.g. correct: `https://www.example.com/es/pagina-en-espanol` ... wrong: `https://www.example.com/pagina-en-espanol`.

Comment: Example on how to add `_language`: https://github.com/b13/warmup/blob/v1.3.3/Classes/Service/PageWarmupService.php#L81

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, the native way described by @mathias-brodala might not be sufficient. In those cases you will need a proper TSFE otherwise you do not have all the TypoScript settings that might influence link generation.

For these cases you basically need to create an instance of the `TypoScriptFrontendController` yourself, call setup methods and inject real or mocked dependencies like `FrontendUserAuthentication` depending on your usecase.

A working solution for TYPO3v9, for instance, can be found in the 
[rx_scheduled_social extension](https://bitbucket.org/reelworx/rx_scheduled_social/src/8a2844d76b2e443e52b23a1eae131a7bbca86109/Classes/Utility/LinkUtility.php).